# Entity Framework Stored Procedure only returning one result

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

```
List<GetAllDataResult> list = myContext.GetAllData(id).ToList();
```

So consider the above call to a stored procedure using Entity Framework. When I call it, I am expecting 5 rows to be returned (which I will enumerate through) but the call is only returning one row - looks like the first row.

This is the method in the EF designer Code:
    public ObjectResult GetAllData(Nullable id)();

Why is it not returning a list.

When I run the SP manually in Sql Server Management Studio, I am getting the correct list.
Any ideas?

Update: The Stored Procedure being executed is as follows:

```
Select id, Name, age from Person where lid = @id
```

In SQL profiler I can see the call as follows:

```
exec [dbo].[GetAllData] @id=2
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `GetAllData` method?

Comment: It's just the designer generated code from EF

Comment: Can you run profiler to ensure the query that is being executed?

Comment: Yeah the Profiler runs in the correct place.
One thing the SP does is mark some rows in the database as "Delt with" so when you run it again, you don't get the same results back.
We had thought that something was "lazy loading" the SP call and then later running it again (for a second time), but the Profiler only shows one call.

Comment: Can you post the SP code, as well as the query being executed in Profiler?

Comment: The SP when run manually correctly gets the number of rows I'm looking for: The comment box isn't big enough to paste it in. To summarise it does a 

"Select id, Name, age from Person where lid = @id" and returns 5 rows.

Comment: Profiler output call says:
exec [dbo].[GetAllData] @id=2

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please also update your original post w/ the SP code for `GetAllData`.

Comment: is id a unique field or key on your table? and is the sql you run in management studio exactly the same as the sql from profiler?

Comment: The SQL being run is exactly the same in both Mgt Studio and from EF in Visual Studio. 

The variable I am passing in, is a foreign key and therefore will return several rows. The result is passed to an ObjectResult<> which only contains 1 row, where it should contain multiple.

Answer (score 0):

In your EF designer can you check your mappings?

I have the assumption that, if you generated the entities automatically from the Database it's actually mapping your `@ID` parameter to the ID field of `Person`.

By this, I mean that when EF generates the SQL it may well be generating:

```
     Select id, Name, age from Person where id = @id
```

This can be further checked to see if the row returned has an `ID` of 2, not an `lid`